# Multiple website search problems.PLZ HELP

Tags: magento-1.9

I set up multiple websites (parked domain method) and the default website works perfectly. However, when I test the second website. The search function is not working, it always redirect into the current page without loading the search result(Eg. If I click search at the homepage it will go homepage or if I click search at the about us page then it will go to about us page)

I used Magento1.9.2.4 free template from template monster. This template uses cmsmart extension for doing the search. There are two kinds of search method. One is typing the keyword in the input text box and clicking the search button(This one works), the other is selecting the category type in the select box and then clicking the search button.(This one doesn't work)

The domain name we used is as following:

www.aricare.com.au(working one with the search)
www.shavingclub.com.au(not working one with the search when selecting the category from the select box and then clicking the search button)

Is it a redirect issue? I tried .htaccess and index.php separately but still can't fix the issue. （everything works fine except the second website's ajax search function）
－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－ －－－－－－－
.htaccess setting

RewriteBase /welcome/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)shavingclub.com.au
RewriteRule ^ - [E=MAGE_RUN_CODE:shavingclub]
－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－ －－－－－－－
index.php

switch($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) {

// shavingclub.com.au
case 'shavingclub.com.au':
case 'www.shavingclub.com.au':
Mage::run('shavingclub', 'website');
break;

// Mainstore.com (default store)
default:
Mage::run($mageRunCode, $mageRunType);
break;
}

Will it be a parameter lost issue? When I search at the default website, the url will be sth like "http://www.aricare.com.au/welcome/catalogsearch/result/?search_categories[]=103&q="
However, when I search at the second website the above url is not showing in the browser.

PLZ HELP. Thank you in advance.

Comment: 2nd method is from the theme?

Comment: Yes，use the same theme as the main website

Comment: The second website is using the same theme as the main website and the both of the search methods are from the theme

Comment: I just tested the search functionality and is working for me... here is the url result.
http://www.shavingclub.com.au/welcome/catalogsearch/result/?search_categories%5B%5D=123&q=pace

Comment: Yep, I typed "pace" after the suggestion show ups i just wait to suggestion hide then click on men category > search button.

Comment: Thanks for helping. Typing the keyword inside the search box and clicking the search button is working. However, select the category type from the select box and clicking the search button will stay at the current page without showing the search result.

Comment: And that behavior is correct, bc if you don't type anything on search box shouldn't try to search anything. Make sense?, I think that is correct.

Comment: However,  the search function works at the main website (www.aricare.com.au). I think the search function is either search by the key word or search by the drop down category type

Comment: I think I found the issue... after I understand the problem, let me check something and I'll post the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much. The link for the template I uesd is here [link](http://www.templatemonster.com/free-magento-1-9-template.html#gref)

Answer (score 1):

@Disheng,

I just review the flow of catalogsearch/result action page, and I 100% sure if you try to search with a "empty" query_text (q=[empty]) you will be redirect to the current page you are (behavior you are getting in the second website).

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $query = Mage::helper('catalogsearch')->getQuery();
    /* @var $query Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Query */

    $query->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId());

    if ($query->getQueryText() != '') { //your q is empty so
    ...... 
    } else {
        $this->_redirectReferer(); // you are redirect to current page
    }
```

So Please check under you admin section or theme configuration if under the System > Configuration > Catalog > Catalog > Catalog Search you can change something and make the same configuration to the other site.

I try to create a empty query under Catalog > Search Terms but was impossible, you can't create a empty query_text.

Hope all this information can help to configure your second site.

Best,
Alejandro.

Comment: Thank you again. However, I think if the q is empty, it will use the other search method. If I type the following link                     http://www.aricare.com.au/welcome/catalogsearch/result/?search_categories[]=103&q=          it works. However, If I type the http://www.shavingclub.com.au/welcome/catalogsearch/result/?search_categories[]=123&q=         it won't work

Answer (score 0):

Finally fixed the problem. Thank you, GrinGo. This problem is because of the `getQueryText()` is `''` as GrinGo mentioned. However the solution is very strange. Comment out the above redirect code will make the search works. But it is not good to change the Magento core code. To fix the problem, get rid of the records from `catalogsearch_query` table and `catalogsearch_result` table manually (`delete * from catalogsearch_query` -_-! ) and then create a new query record related to the website's category. Change the value of the synonym_for column from null to empty (just untick the null value in the `catalogsearch_query` table).

Notice: null value of the synonym_for column stop the search functions of cmsmart extension. It could be the bug from cmsmart extension or from Magento. cheers!

Comment: Glad to here that, please mark answer as correct so the question can be closed